# cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]' when using In clause with linq

Tags: c#, linq, select, where-clause, in-clause

This is the query i tried but above error is coming.
b is a comma seperated list. image shows the output of b.

```
var CheckInHand = from item in PaymentList
                  where item.Id.In(b)          
                  select item.TotalAmt;
```

[image is the comma seperated list which is b]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y39bd.png

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, `In` expects a `string[]` and you're attempting to pass `b` which is a `string`?

You can convert your comma-separated `string` into a `string[]` using [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0).

```
var CheckInHand = from item in PaymentList
                  where item.Id.In(b.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                  select item.TotalAmt;
```

Comment: Thanks its worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to @dakota-methvin, this may be relevant.

```
        [Fact]
        public void AssertItem()
        {
            var b = new int[] {311, 306, 299, 303, 304, 302, 301, 291, 281};
            var PaymentList = new Payment[] {new Payment() {Id = 311, TotalAmt = 500}};
            var CheckInHand = from item in PaymentList
                where b.Contains(item.Id)
                select item.TotalAmt.ToString("$##.00");
            Assert.Equal("$500.00",CheckInHand.First());
        }

        public class Payment
        {
            public int TotalAmt { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }
```